# Use TexLive 2016

Tags: upgrade, latex, texlive

Ok, so I needed some features from TexLive 2016.

The latest Ubuntu/Debian package that I can see is for TexLive 2013, so I went to the TexLive website and got my files from there. I ran the installer, and after 45 minutes I am "Welcome to TexLive!".

Also, I modified my `PATH`, `MANPATH` and `INFOPATH` according to the instructions that I got from the installer.

However, if I `lualatex my_awesome_file.tex` in a terminal, Ubuntu still calls TexLive 2013. Also, `luatex --version` returns `blah blah blah TexLive2013 blah blah`.

How do I tell my Ubuntu to use TexLive 2016?

Edit: my `$PATH` returns

```
bash: /home/adaldo/catkin_ws/devel/bin:/opt/ros/indigo/bin:/home/adaldo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games: No such file or directory
```

Comment: These commands will output the status of the current $PATH. `echo $PATH`,  `which lualatex`

Comment: Not sure I understand, but: `echo $PATH` returns a list of folders separated by colons; `which lualatex` returns `usr/bin/lualatex`. This folder is not in the `PATH`, but its parent `usr/bin` is.

Comment: "echo $PATH returns a list of folders separated by colons" ok, it is important. You must add this output  to your question.

Comment: Perhaps, your $ PATH does not include a path of TeXLive. Do you remember where you have installed the TeXLive?

Comment: To invoke TexLive you must use a command like `pdflatex`. [LuaTex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LuaTeX) is something different. Also, the latest Debian package is TexLive 2015, not 2013.

Comment: You can find the answers at tex.stackexchange.com, in particular [here
](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu). I recomand you not the accepted answer, but the answer by Silke, which is based among other sources on [this article](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100gregorio.pdf).